# Is the translation of Qur'an 4:40 "If there be a good deed, He will repay twofold" inaccurate?

Tags: arabic-translation, surat-an-nisa

The translation of the Qur'an by Maulana Wahiduddin Khan contains:

> God does not wrong anyone by as much as a grains weight. If there be a good deed, **He will repay twofold**, and will bestow out of His own bounty an immense reward. -- Qur'an 4:40 (translation available from [Islam Awakened](http://islamawakened.com/quran/4/40))

I'm skeptical at the word "twofold" here in particular, and I see that other translations do not use that word.  I want to check if this specific numerical increase (a factor of two) in good deeds is supported (or even partially implied) by the Arabic text.

**Question**: Is the translation of Qur'an 4:40 "If there be a good deed, He will repay twofold" inaccurate?

Tafsir suggest it's a "doubling", but it's still not clear:

> (He will double it) from one to ten times (and will give (the doer) from His presence an immense reward) an abundant reward in Paradise. -- [Tanwîr al-Miqbâs min Tafsîr Ibn ‘Abbâs](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=73&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=40&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)
>
> ...and if it be a good deed, He will double it, and it cannot be a good deed unless it is [done] for Him -- [Kashani Tafsir](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=107&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=40&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)
>
> ...if it be a good deed, He will double it and give from Himself a great wage. -- [Al Qushairi Tafsir](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=108&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=40&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)

Comment: ضاعف 
*da'afa* doesn't necessary means to double (it can generally mean multiplay with a certain factor), but if you said ضاعف ضعفين *da'afa di'fayn* it would clearly mean double as you multiplayed with the factor two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation is indeed inaccurate. The [verse](http://islamawakened.com/quran/4/40/) says:

> #### إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَظْلِمُ مِثْقَالَ ذَرَّةٍ وَإِن تَكُ حَسَنَةً يُضَاعِفْهَا وَيُؤْتِ مِن لَّدُنْهُ أَجْرًا عَظِيمًا

The Arabic word يُضَاعِفْهَا means multiply. It is not restricted to two-fold or double, but can be used to describe any multiplier.

Islamically, in [al-Baqarah 2:261](http://islamawakened.com/quran/2/261/), one can see that Allah uses the same word to describe 700 times the reward. In [Sahih Muslim 1151 e](https://sunnah.com/muslim/13/213), the same word is used to describe 10-700 folds.

Lingguistically, the [word ضِعْف](http://www.baheth.info/all.jsp?term=%D8%B6%D8%B9%D9%81)ُ on its own is commonly used to describe double, but is not restricted to only twofold, albeit the most commonly understood meaning (as in Lesan al-Arab):

> #### وقال الزجاج: ضِعْفُ الشيء مِثْلُه الذي يُضَعِّفُه، وأَضْعافُه أَمثالُه
>
> Al-Zajjaj said: *di'f* means double, our multiples.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from the dictionary meaning [here](https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D9%8A%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%81/)

> *ضاعف العددَ جعله ضعفين ( مثلين ) أو أكثر*
>
> it will be doubled or more

Or at another line it says:

> *زادها*
>
> increase

So from what I can see it means 2X or more.

The translation provided on [Quran.com](https://quran.com/4/40) also says:

"He **multiplies** it and gives from Himself a great reward."